# Add lines when a specific value is entered (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

I have a project with employees (Employee 1 to 8) and their monthly schedule and I have 2 (or more) work posts. Their shift numbers are 1,2 and 3.
Let's say S1 is the 1st post and S2 is the second. Employees 1 to 4 are normally scheduled for S1 and 5-8 for S2.
When I need an employee from S1 to work a shift on S2, I put this shift on his S1 line with an indicator (e.g. 2 S02) and I have a second sheet which reads all the shifts with Index/match (I need to have the whole program in one line so I can make some other calculations on the 2nd sheet). Then at the 1st sheet I have all the employees on both posts (so both posts have 8 lines), with the extra lines for each one, hidden with a counta function and a 0/1 filter, which contain a simple if function that returns only the shift number and not the post indicator. These lines read the value from the second sheet and return the shift that is inserted at the other post, so when the filtered counta value becomes 1, I have a vba command that executes re-apply filter every time a value is inserted, so the line appears.
This approach is making the workbook too laggy, when working with 100 employees and 20 posts.
Is there a way to make the lines appear with another lighter method?

In the 1st picture you can see how the sheet looks when not filtered and in the 2nd, how it looks filtered.

The VBA command I use is the following:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
   Sheets("SHIFTS").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please edit your question, adding the VBA "command" you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I understand your problem: currently at every change of your worksheet (so every cell which is filled in), the autofilter is re-applied, heavily slowing down your Excel file.

I see two possible outcomes for this:

1. Either you foresee some form where people can enter all values for a certain employee, and when they click the "Ok" button, the values get filled in and than your re-apply the filter. (Obviously this means that you need to remove the mentioned macro).
2. Either you mention that the autofilter only needs to be applied in case a certain value is entered (let's say column "E"), this can be done as follows:

   ```
   Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
     If Target.Column = 5 'Column "E" stands for .Column number 5
     Then Sheets("SHIFTS").AutoFilter.ApplyFilter
     End If
   End Sub
   ```

Comment: The 1st is what I currently do but it's not easy for other colleagues that use the form and have no excel knowledge besides entering values. The second one I don't really get. Do you suggest adding a column where I should store all the specific values? Because this isn't possible as there are endless combinations. Anyway I was looking for a different approach on adding the extra lines without having them there but hidden because for eg 120 employees and 20 posts, I need a sheet with 4000 lines, most of them with functions so the sheet becomes too heavy even without the VBA macro. Thanks.

Comment: @RagnarNightwalker: this is maybe not the kind of answer you're looking for, but why do you need to re-apply that autofilter anyway and automatically? You can tell the customers how to start an autofilter, you can create a button that enables the autofilter, ..., but I don't understand why you need to pass all this trouble, just for showing something that simple as an autofilter.

Comment: Because when we need to create the schedule for a whole month and we need to do those employee transfers from post to post regularly, 1 mistake when re-applying the filter (forgotten or something) can lead to a lot of wasted work-hours. Better safe than sorry. That's why I need the extra lines appearing instantly.